# addEventListener not working on html button

Tags: javascript, html

Simple html button that I want to alert when clicked.

```
HTML:
<div id="container>
    <button type="button>Click Me</button>
</div>

Javascript:
var cat = document.getElementById("container");
var dog = cat.getElementsByTagName("button");
function mouse (){
    alert("mouse")
};
dog.addEventListener("click", mouse, false);
```

If I target the container with:

```
cat.addEventListener("click", mouse, false);
```

Works fine anytime I click on the div, but when I try to add it to the button, nothing happens. I have also tried...

```
dog.addEventListener("click, mouse(), false);
```

When I try that code, the mouse function runs on load.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of node list. There are actually multiple errors there with missing quotes in HTML, button close tag having a typo etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JS is wrong:

Instead of `GetElementById` should be `getElementById`. Javascript is case sensitive.

And I don't see where do you have `hide` function declaration. I see only `mouse` function that is never used.

Also according to @Harry comment by calling `getElementsByTagName` you will get DOM elements collection. So you should use:

```
dog[ 0 ].addEventListener("click", hide, false);
```

Comment: I incorrectly typed the code here. I assure you my code syntax is correct. Fixed it! Thank You!

Comment: You mistyped your button code, too. It is <button type="button>Click Me</butto> and should be <button type="button">Click Me</button>.

Answer (score 0):

lots of misspellings

```
//get not Get
var cat = document.getElementById("container");
//get first of array
var dog = cat.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
function mouse (){
    alert("mouse")
};
//no hide function
dog.addEventListener("click", mouse, false);
```